# Magic Square using numbers 4-12

Tags: magic-square, magic

I have to make a magic square using number 4-12.

Comment: GentlePurpleRain's answer here explains this http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/magic-square-using-consecutive-odd-numbers-5-through-11/31988#31988

Answer (score 0):

> 5 | 10 | 9
>  12|  8 | 4
>  7 |  6 | 11

The idea is:

> Make the original square with numbers 1 to 9 and add 3 to every number.